# Regex to allow only # in the string and block the special characters

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex to allow the contents but block the special characters `'` and `--` in the string. I am working on a product which uses the regex to allow or block contents goofing around the product, I managed to find the below pattern:

```
^('|--|#|\\x27|\\x23)$
```

Which is supposed to match `--`, `'` and `#` in the string, but when I tested this pattern in some online regex pattern matching. it was not highlighting the string when it contains `--`, `'` or `#`.

Comment: Because of the anchors. Remove them and you will get matches inside strings. See [`(--|\x27|\x23)`](https://regex101.com/r/sI2lB8/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks mate. it worked. But I have a question, based on the online reading ^ and $ denotes start and end of string. Unable to understand why this is causing the problem.

Comment: Not "start and end of the *pattern*" but "start and end of the string you're matching the pattern against". Your regex means "from the start of the line, match one of those 5 things, and then hit the end of the line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [*Start of String and End of String Anchors* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi):

> The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string. Applying `^a` to `abc` matches `a`. `^b` does not match `abc` at all, because the `b` cannot be matched right after the start of the string, matched by `^`.
>
> Similarly, `$` matches right after the last character in the string. `c$` matches `c` in `abc`, while `a$` does not match at all.

Also, `\x27` matches a `'`, and `\x23` matches a `#`, thus, no need doubling them with literals.

So, you just need

```
(--|\x27|\x23)
```

Or (using a non-capturing group):

```
(?:--|\x27|\x23)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI2lB8/1)